# Is it possible to get value from div role="textbox"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a textbox using role="textbox" in html. Is it possible to get value from it using angular9 or javascript? I don't want to use `<textarea>` or `<input>`.

```css
div{
min-height: 200px;
min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtboxLabel">Enter your five-digit zipcode</div>
<div role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-placeholder="5-digit zipcode" aria-labelledby="txtboxLabel"></div>
```

Somehow stackoverflow doesn't run this snippet. You can try it any html editor. My question was about is there a way to retrieve the value from a div role="textbox".

Comment: `document.getElementById("x").textContent`

Comment: `document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `querySelector` by targeting the property of `div` or use unique `Id` on div to get the data using `document.getElementById`

```js
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText
  alert(text)
}
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="txtboxLabel">Enter your five-digit zipcode</div>
<button onclick=getText()>
Get TextBox Data
</button>
<div role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-placeholder="5-digit zipcode" aria-labelledby="txtboxLabel">34567</div>
```

Comment: if jquery `$("[role=textbox]").text('something')`

Comment: its a div. it wont have `text()` function. `textarea` can be used. also OP is to get the data your logic is setting data.

Comment: `text()` can be used for divs as well. But the thing you said about OPs intention was right though

Comment: .innerText to get data? Please try running your code before sharing.

Comment: @Professorval I like your confidence. go through basic JS+HTML or run the above code snippet.